# XeLaTeX and sans serif math

Tags: xetex, sans-serif, math-fonts

I want to include some `TeX` output (mainly math) in an `SVG` image. The `SVG` is meant to be used in a presentation and I would like to use a `sans serif font` for this (currently, I use `Biolinum` but another font would be acceptable as well).

The font used in the `TeX` output should match the one used in the `SVG`. Therefore, I am using `XeLaTeX` and set the font to the same I am using for the text in the `SVG`.

The problem is with the math parts of the `TeX` output. Ideally, I would like to make the font used there to match the one of the text. After some searching, I understand that (currently) there is no `sans serif font` which fully supports `Unicode math`. However, is there some way to get "as close as possible"? What I mean by this is a setting where the glyphs from the font get used whenever possible and, if the font does not provide something, some fallback (which looks similar) is used.

What I currently have is the following:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{mathspec}
\setallmainfonts(Digits,Latin,Greek){Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document} 
  $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} a \gamma i \Sigma$ γ​ɣ\textit{a} Σ
  \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: visual output]

However, as you can see, the font, for example, provides a capital Sigma but it is not used for the sum. Even worse, the Sigma used for the sum has serifs and looks a bit out of place.

Please note that this is meant as an example and that I am looking for a more general answer to the problem (than, e.g., replacing the sum by a capital Sigma).